# Asymptotic Inconsistency with Numerical Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

I have this equation
$\frac{dB(x)}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}[x^3B(x)+K][A(x)+B(x)]$

Where K is a positive constant and $x>0, A(x)>0$ and $A(x)$ is falling off like exponential.

if I assume $B(x)$ falls off like exponenential (in general, falls off that smaller than $\frac{1}{x^n}$ for all finite n as $x\rightarrow\infty$) then I have
$\frac{dB(x)}{dx}\sim-\frac{K}{x^2}[A(x)+B(x)]$
$\Rightarrow B\sim e^{K/x}\int_x^\infty dq \frac{e^{-K/q}{A(q)}}{q^2}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

So if $A(x)$ is falling off like exponential, this is a consistent asymptotic.

However,when I numerically solve the original equation (1st equation) on Mathematica, I can perfectly fit $B(x)$ proportional to $\frac{1}{x^2}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

This is a behavior of solution when $x^3B(x)$ cannot be ignored compared to $K$ in the equation. What's more, if we have $\frac{dB(x)}{dx}\sim-\frac{1}{x^2}[x^3B(x)][B(x)]$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

i.e., ignoring K and $A(x)$ in the original equation. We get $B(x)$ proportional to $\frac{1}{x^2}$ like the numerical solution.

My question is that why the consistent asymptotic behavior did not show up in the numerical solution?  How do I show $B\sim e^{K/x}\int_x^\infty dq \frac{e^{-K/q}{A(q)}}{q^2}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ will yield singular behavior at some x so that the numerical solution did not "choose" this answer?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only made plausible that one solution with such asymptotics exists, but how can you hope to guess the initial condition giving that solution? Moreover, that's not stable, numerical errors will lead it to another, dominating behavior. It's a [Riccati differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation), so its solution can be represented (in this special case) as $B(x)=-x u'(x)/u(x)$, where $u$ satisfies a *linear* differential equation of second order. So $u$ will be a linear combination of two independent solutions, probably with very different asymptotics, and one may soon dominate. You can try to write down the differential equation for $B(x_{max}-t)=y(t),$ and solve that numerically for the initial condition $y(0)=0$. That should give you the solution approaching $0$ quickly, backwards from $x_{max}$.